# why UIScrollView is leaving space from top in ios 6 and ios 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uiscrollview, ios7

[image]

[image]

I have turned off Autolayout and viewcontroller is embedded in navigation controller.
I am using Xcode 5, Storyboard.

I don't understand why is it leaving space from top.
Actually in storyboard i have put my label exactly below navigation bar.
But when i run it on simulator then it leaves space from top.

One of the hacky way to resolve this

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
   self.scrollViewMain.frame = CGRectMake(0, -70, 320, 800);

   self.scrollViewMain.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 800);
}
```

**But am i missing something very simple approach.**

Answer (score 159, accepted):

In Xcode 5, in storyboard select your controller > in Attribute Inspector disable Adjust Scroll View Insets
Also check if you have set any contentInset

**Edit** : I attached a pic

[image]

Comment: I can tell you where to check on
check the contentInset, also try disabling under top bars and bottom bar from the picture above, check if you have set deltas to any view

Comment: Thank you. I have been going crazy trying to figure out something so simple.

Comment: Be mindful of `navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height` and `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height`. Those can cause `UIScrollView.contentSize` calculation issues as well.

Comment: then my scrollview is not scrolling

Comment: What is the reason for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691614/why-is-uiscrollview-leaving-space-on-top-and-does-not-scroll-to-the-bottom

Comment: @JayeshMiruliya you linked another question, which isn't yours and its old, he needs to uncheck Under Top Bar on his controller

Comment: This is the moment when I regret I can give only one thumbs up :) thanks for help!

Comment: Some times what seems to be a big problem (thinking you messed up constraints) is just something else. Gargh!!

Answer (score 85):

The fix is to implement the following line of code after in the viewDidLoad;

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

Comment: Perfect for me. Thanks

Comment: thanks you save lot of time, i had no clue, why there is extra space.

Answer (score 40):

**Update for iOS 11**

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I could not figure out why my padding was wrong. I tried automaticallyAdjustScrollInsets everywhere, but I was on iOS 11, hence why it wasn't working

Comment: I tried this today - March 22, 2021 and it is should be marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

Inspector: Select scrollView and set up Content Insets - **never**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Easiest solution.

Answer (score 8):

> Go to main storyboard. Select view controller, see property "Adjust
>   Scroll view Insects" in attribute inspector. if you do not want top
>   spacing.then uncheck "Under Top Bars". if you don not want bottom
>   spacing.then uncheck "Under Bottom Bars". this kind of problem come
>   when we use scroll view related controllers.
>
> This is a feature for navigation and tab bar to adjust content in scroll view like controls.

Comment: Thanks , its simple now

Answer (score 4):

For me in xcode 7 and Swift 2.x I was populating a UIScrollView with a for loop and had to set the contentInset to zero.

```
for image in images {
  self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

Comment: Works. Thanks webjunkie.

Comment: @alsantos123 I'm glad it did!. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your StoryBoard, select ContentInsets to never:

[image]