# Why is UIScrollView leaving space on top and does not scroll to the bottom

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am new to objective-C programming.

I am using UIScrollView with some labels, image and text view on it.

I have turned off Autolayout and already tried with "Adjust scroll View Insets" on (situation described in title) and off (doesn't scroll).

This is what I insert into viewDidLoad:

```
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 687)];
```

But I must be missing something very simple.

Comment: Try with large number in contentSize like CGSizeMake(320, 1687)

Comment: It works. Thx. But I still have some empty space on top.

Comment: Uncheck Under Top Bars on your controller

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> 1... Why is UIScrollView leaving space on top

**With Storyboard**- Goto view controller > Attribute Inspector > Uncheck Adjust Scroll View Insets property

**With Code**- For extra space set `viewController` property  `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `NO`, by default it is `YES`.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false; 
scroller.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
scroller.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
scroller.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
```

> 2... does not scroll to the bottom

To make it scroll try with large number in `contentSize` like `CGSizeMake(320, 1687)`. If it works that means you are not setting the `contentSize` large enough to have all its content.

Answer (score 34):

Just select your view controller and set shown option to false (uncheck)

[image: ViewController Inspector]

Answer (score 29):

**iOS 11 && 12**

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Comment: iOS 12: scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never

Answer (score 28):

**iOS 11**

In my case only changing this UIScrollView Content Insets property in IB from `Automatic` to `Never` helped.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was going crazy on this problem, this is the only thing I've missed!

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3.0**

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero

scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero;
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the margin has nothing to do with `ScrollViewInsets` or `contentOffset`. It's just a conflict between `SuperView.Top` and `SafeArea.Top` pinning, happens when you pin the UIScrollView to top, bottom, left and right.

This is the right way to cover the top margin.

1) Pin all the four sides.

[image: Pinning]

2) Select the top constraint > Change Second Item to `Superview.Top`

[image: conflict]

3) Then the last step is to change the Constant to 0 (Zero).
[image]

You might want to check this too:
https://github.com/29satnam/MoveTextFieldWhenKeyboardAppearsSwift

Answer (score 2):

I did below, my problem solved

changing UIScrollView Content Insets property in from `Automatic` to `Never` and Adding below code in `viewDidLoad()`

```
scroller.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
scroller.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
scroller.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);`
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On iPhoneX this will also occur due to some non-sense safe area stuff that auto-layout tried to account for. Fix (for iPhoneX) with this:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view .m file, use this code to fix this problem

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    // To fix iOS8 bug of scrollView autolayout
    if([[[[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] == 8){
        [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero

scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero;    

scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 *(Auto Layout)***

1. Change "Layout Margins" to explicit
2. Set margins to your needs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,

```
_scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
_scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

After user interface orientation going to landscape, my UIScrollView shown its UIScrollIndicator being misplaced. To fix this, you need to add the following code.

As per iOS 13, yet supporting iOS 12 and earlier:

```
    // Fixes the scroll indicator misplacement when rotated in landscape
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        v.automaticallyAdjustsScrollIndicatorInsets = false
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        v.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    }

    v.contentInset = .zero
    v.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero
```