# Remove extra bottom padding from horizontal UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, ios8, autolayout

I have created a horizontally scrolling `UIScrollView` which contains `UIButton`s. I want the `UIButton`s to fill the height of the `UIScrollView`, so I've set up auto layout for the buttons: the top space and bottom space are set to Superview with a constant of 0. In Interface Builder it shows the correct `UIScrollView` frame size, but the buttons are 10 pixels too small - there's extra padding underneath the buttons. The scroll view's height is 44 pixels, the buttons height are 34 pixels.

I thought this might be because it preserves some space to show the horizontal scroll bar. But I have disabled Shows Horizontal Indicator in IB. I then attempted to programmatically remove the space via the code below but that didn't change anything.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)
```

EDIT: It must not be related to preserving space for a scroll bar. The scroll view's height is equal to the height of another button. When I change that button's height to change the scroll view height, the amount of bottom spacing increases. The buttons are always 34pt tall.

Another thing I tried was to remove the bottom space and add a fixed height constraint, but this results in an ambiguous scroll view height.

How can this padding be removed so that the buttons are the exact height of the scroll view's height?

Interface Builder:
[image]

Running the app:
[image]
(I temporarily unhid the scroll bar to show it here)
I need the white button to stretch in height to cover up the gray area beneath it.

Comment: Is it always a 10pt difference, no matter what scroll view height?

Comment: @hlfcoding The scroll view's height is equal to the height of another button. When I change that button's height to change the scroll view height, the amount of spacing increases! The buttons are always 34pt tall. So it's not related to space preserved for a scroll bar. Will update question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. I simply had to specify the height of the first button to be equal to the scroll view height, while preserving the top and bottom constraints. This must have updated the scroll view's content size because the other buttons that were set to only have a top and bottom constraint to the superview stretched to fill the space where that padding previously existed. There are no warnings or errors in Interface Builder and displays as expected on my device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691614/why-is-uiscrollview-leaving-space-on-top-and-does-not-scroll-to-the-bottom

Answer (score 0):

I believe for UIScrollView to work with AutoLayout you'll need to wrap its subviews with an inner 'content' view as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```