# ScrollView adds space at the top of subview xcode 6 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, xcode6

I'm trying to build a scene using story board. In that I've a scrollView, which has the following constraints.

[image: ScrollView Constraints]

Inside the scroll view I've a plain view, which has the following constraints.

[image: View Constraints]

Now inside the view I've several labels and other objects. For the first label I've a top Space from view as 0. But the following result appears.

[image]

You can notice the space above the label "Type".

Please help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select ViewControler(RED)

[image: select ViewControler(RED)]

Chose Attributes Inspector and uncheck Adjust Scroll View Insets

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. May I know what's the use of this property ?

Comment: not sure why it is checked, it appeared with iOS7 and its 40px the same size of the navigation bar so i assume it has something have to do with iOS6 and iOS7 case iOS6 you need it must be YES because you have the navbar and it is not transparent and you need the 40px space else NO. But not sure

Comment: Now scroll is not working. When I turn to Landscape mode few views are missing.

Comment: well thats another question, and its abou autolayout...you need to figure it out and place the right constraints...it is a little bit tricky

Comment: Right constraints in the sense ? Are there any sets of constraints that I should avoid or use ? And my sub views are just labels stacked one above the other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691614/why-is-uiscrollview-leaving-space-on-top-and-does-not-scroll-to-the-bottom

Comment: This was driving me f***ing insane!