# UIScrollView not scrolling after Unchecking "Adjust scroll view insets" xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, xcode6, autolayout

In my app, I tried to use scroll view. But I encountered an issue where the scroll view added space at the top and bottom, as mentioned in the following question.

[ScrollView adds space at the top of subview xcode 6 Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547149/scrollview-adds-space-at-the-top-of-subview-xcode-6-swift/27547371#27547371)

I was asked to uncheck "Adjust scroll view insets" of the containing view controller. Doing that  solved my purpose.

But the scroll view isn't scrolling anymore. I'm not able to scroll to the views which are appearing at the bottom.

May I know what I need to do, to make it work ?. Thanks.

Comment: What is your scroll view's `contentSize`?

Comment: I am using storyboard. And I didn't mention contentSize anywhere. Should I? How should I calculate while using autoLayout ?

Comment: Prese How you fixed this issue , I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 6):

The way I solved the extra padding between the top label and the nav bar was by unchecking "Under Top Bars" in the attributes inspector, in the "Extended Edges" section. When you uncheck it, items on your storyboard may move around. Don't re-arrange them. Run simulator and it should work.

Note: leave "Adjust Scroll View Insets" checked, otherwise nothing scrolls.

My attributes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. This is how it worked for me. I added a screen shot of my object hierarchy

1. Leave Adjust Scroll View Insets checked.
2. Drag a view and place it in your Scroll View, cover the entire storyboard. This view will hold every UI object in your storyboard
3. Add top, right, bottom, left = 0 constraints from your Scroll view to Main View.
4. Add top, right, bottom, left = 0 constraints from your content view to Main View.
5. Add constraints from your UI object relative to your content view.

The imageView is placed under the navigation bar. Top, right, left constraints are set to 0 relative to content view. When I run the app my image appears right below the navigation bar.

[image]

Comment: It isn't working. Between, in my object hierarchy it appears as "view" only, not "content view" as in your case. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Without adding constraints such as "Align center to x and align center to y" to the "view" xcode is issuing warnings.

Comment: doesn't appear to work. I still get the padding between the top label and the top of the view.

Answer (score -3):

Define in the viewDidLoad

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```