# Clickable content of UIScrollview is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `UIScrollView` to display the list of contacts available. Top-Half of the content links are still clickable, but the Bottom-Half *(the links not appearing on the screen)* are not clickable. They all have the same action, All contents are appearing on the scroll but actions are not there for the Bottom-Half of the content.

I already tried setting up these:

```
self->_scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

**Below is the image for describe my problem**

[image: Below is the image for describe my problem]

Comment: usually it means your constraints are not proper

Comment: i think your Inner page is not updating height as per scrollview so thats why bottom link is not clickable.

Comment: @SahilManchanda Hi, i did provide an image link for the elements and constraints.

Comment: @BhaveshNayi Hi, earlier i did try to update the height of the `Inner Page View` and the content of the whole table view is cutting off

Comment: issue is not updating inner view height so try to reset constraints.

Comment: @BhaveshNayi Hi, did fixed the issue. I updated the inner view height and set the constraint priority of "Align Center Y to Superview" to 250

Comment: now working or not ?

Comment: @BhaveshNayi working now. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome bro. happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

I updated the `Inner Page View` height and update the priority of `Align Center Y to Superview` to 250 instead of 1000.

[UIButtons at the bottom of UIScrollView not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134484/uibuttons-at-the-bottom-of-uiscrollview-not-working/46530595#46530595)