# Top space on device rotation

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, ios-autolayout

I have the following constraints on my UIView in portrait mode:

[image: Portrait]

And landscape:

[image: Landscape]

This is screenshot of the ViewController when I open it first time:

[image: Portrait 1]

Top space is OK.

Then I'm rotating the device to landscape:

[image: Landscape]

Do you see that white space on the top?

And when I'm rotating it back to landscape, the space still stays:

[image: Portrait 2]

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: I think its your background color of view, just set background color of view as clear color and try it

Comment: @Jecky that was the first thing I've checked — it's not bg of view which displays content, it's bg of the parent view.

Comment: @RankoR Had you try to  uncheck `Adjust scrollview insets` in viewcontroller attributes

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 can you please post this as answer? It helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to uncheck `Adjust scrollview insets` Of viewcontroller attribute

[image]

Source Of Image: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547371/4601170)

Answer (score 1):

You might have set TopConstraint of your view With margin.

Uncheck box for Add to Margin.

[image]

Comment: I've removed constraint and re-added with unchecked box — still the same behaviour.

Comment: Have you specified different constraint for different orientation?

Answer (score 1):

Considering black view about the imageview which contains Back button is a UIView (says, viewNav)

Constraints for viewNav:

[image]

if you'r changing the height of viewNav of rotation then use size classes as see below and click on landscape option. Now select your navView and click on height constraint and give c-c constraint like this

[image]
[image]

Constraints for UiImageView:

[image]

If you'r image covers the complete screen the give bottom constraint as 0.

This fixes every thing.

If you are using native navigationBar then you there will be no viewNav and now constraint for image will be

[image]

On giving top constraint, don't forget to select `use standard value` for top constraint then enter 64. Bottom and height is according to your need whatever you prefer.