# How to remove the padding-like space in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, autolayout

I have a structure in Xcode like below. I set the constrains and I didn't use `Constrain to margins` and set all numbers to be `0`. However, I still have a padding-like space above my `UIImageView`. I want to remove this, but I don't know where I can configure to do so and why this happened?

[image]

[image]

Actually, I'll following steps of an iOS guide book to practice on this. In it's example, it has `Adjust scroll view insets` checked, but no this padding-like space appears. Is there any solution without unchecking the `Adjust scroll view insets`?[image]

Comment: may be this would help http://stackoverflow.com/a/41225359/4601170

Comment: Is is possible to remove the padding without unchecking `Adjust scroll view insets`?

Comment: yes may be using some blank label before tableview in hierarchy .. check that may be works for you..

Comment: @MarcusThornton can you post the link which tutorial you are following ?