# Is it possible for UIStackView to scroll?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

Let's say I have added more views in UIStackView which can be displayed, how I can make the `UIStackView` scroll?

Comment: Why aren't you using a scroll view with a (or multiple) stack views for the content?

Comment: The one-sentence solution is that for width you control-drag to the grandparent scroll view, **NOT** the parent stack view.  Explained in my answer!

Comment: How to embed UIStackView inside UIScrollView in iOS https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/324

Comment: Regarding this critical question in iOS.  **In fact there are two (and only two) ways to do it** - those are the *only* way to do it and you *must* follow one of the two procedures, exactly.  My answer below is always updated.

Comment: YES. You MUST have an intermediate UIView as content view of UIScrollView. Then place UIStackView as child view of content view. https://www.raywenderlich.com/2198310-uistackview-tutorial-for-ios-introducing-stack-views

Answer (score 740, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for a solution **without code**, I created an example to do this completely in the storyboard, using Auto Layout.

You can get it from [github](https://github.com/ar-juan/uistackview-in-uiscrollview).

Basically, to recreate the example (for vertical scrolling):

1. Create a `UIScrollView`, and set its constraints.
2. Add a `UIStackView` to the `UIScrollView`
3. Set the constraints: `Leading`, `Trailing`, `Top` & `Bottom` should be equal to the ones from `UIScrollView`
4. Set up an equal `Width` constraint between the `UIStackView` and `UIScrollView`.
5. Set Axis = Vertical, Alignment = Fill, Distribution = Equal Spacing, and Spacing = 0 on the `UIStackView`
6. Add a number of `UIViews` to the `UIStackView`
7. Run

Exchange `Width` for `Height` in step 4, and set `Axis` = `Horizontal` in step 5, to get a horizontal UIStackView.

Comment: Thanks! "4. Set up an equal Width constraint between the UIStackView and UIScrollView." was the key ;)

Comment: Number 6. is also important. Wanted to add all views in code but then Auto Layout shows missing contraints in IB.

Comment: I can't add a width constrant

Comment: Thanks! If someone uses this in an embedded UINavigationViewController and wants to get rid of the top margin, this is the way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30630006/1752287.

Comment: Hi gaes, it seems like this solution doesn't work for horizontal scrolling. On step 4, instead of set equal width, I assume to set equal height, and Axis = Horizontal. I tried that and doesn't work.

Comment: Adding a constraint so that the stackview and scrollview have equal widths will remove warnings from interface builder, but then scrolling will be disabled. Scrolling only happens when the content view inside the scrollview is _larger_ than the scrollview!

Comment: These steps worked well but I had to define the height on the views that are embedded in the UIStackView from step #6.

Comment: For adding views in code and muting IB for errors, adding a UIView with height constraint of zero will do the job.

Comment: is it necessary to set spacing = 0? I think the key is Distribution. (haven't test it yet though)

Comment: To elaborate on point 6.  If the stack view had no elements but all the constraints are in place, you get "Scroll View Need constraints for Y position or height".  Just adding a Label in the stack view makes this warning go away!

Comment: I can't get the stackview to go to the top. It always has some offset that says it's zero but isn't actually zero.

Comment: why not set width constraint to scrollView's content width? set width to scrollView's width will make stackView not scrollable :D

Comment: Regarding the missing constraints mentioned by @pre, I added a single `UIView` constrained to a height of zero and the error goes away. Works perfectly at runtime, too.

Comment: If you're still having issues make sure your custom views implement: override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { return size }

Comment: @arjan what needs to change for me to have spacing in between my views?

Comment: @Arjan Thanks for this great solution, it works flawlessly for me (vertical scrolling). But could you elaborate more on the need of step 4.? Is step 1 not enough for providing width constraint?

Comment: @pre you can specify the intrinsic size from the Size Inspector so it doesn't complain about missing constraints :)

Comment: In case if anyone's looking for **bouncing effect** for this set up, make sure to tick *Bounce Vertically* setting on for the scroll view on Storyboard or set `scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true`

Comment: I was adding my UIScrollView and UIStackView programatically. The steps Arjan worked for me on Swift 4, but I just has to add 1 more line of code when constructing my UIStackView:    
`myStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: Why should i set width constraint equals to scroll view? Leading and trailing should caculate the width.

Comment: I had to add a spacer view to the bottom of my stack view to make it scroll when the keyboard is up.

Comment: Steps 1-3 - Ok, in step 4 you could set horizontal center constraint instead, other steps are *EXTRA!* Fix it please

Comment: Just to be clear , my answer below also is exactly for **either pure storyboard or code**.  This answer is not wrong, but my answer is completely up to date for 2019, and, it completely explains the situation including the "two possible methods" to make it work.  Hope it helps someone!

Comment: In step 3 make sure to connect to Content Layout Guide of scrollview

Comment: i love to think on the fact that so many people are bookmarking should tell something about the need to implement it and how easy it is / should be

Answer (score 76):

I present you the right solution

**For Xcode 11+**

**Step 1:**
Add a **ScrollView** and resize it

[image][image]

**Step 2:**
Add **Constraints** for a ScrollView

[image]

**Step 3:**
Add a **StackView** into ScrollView, and resize it.

[image]

**Step 4:**
Add Constraints for a StackView (**Stask View -> Content Layout Guide -> "Leading, Top, Trailing, Bottom"**)

[image]
[image]

**Step 4.1:**
Correct Constraints -> **Constant** (... -> Constant = 0)

[image]
[image]

**Step 5:**
Add Constraints for a StackView (**Stask View -> Frame Layout Guide -> "Equal Widths**")

[image]
[image]

**Step 6 Example:**
Add two UIView(s) with **HeightConstraints** and **RUN**
[image]
[image]

I hope it will be useful for you like

Comment: This is the correct process for Xcode 11 and 12. There are several steps and you must follow them very carefully. Watch this video and that may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmE50giVuLA

Comment: This works great on Xcode 12. Thank you !

Comment: Step 5 should be to create an equal widths constraint with the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` as this will differ if there are safe area insets and cause horizontal scrolling.

Comment: If you have views where the heights will change (i.e. labels) what would you do as you can't have the height constraint?

Comment: Right and reliable, thank you!

Comment: You are the f.ing best ! finally stack-scrool nightmare has been ended

Answer (score 57):

Apple's Auto Layout Guide includes an entire section on [Working with Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html).  Some relevant snippets:

> 4. Pin the content view’s top, bottom, leading, and trailing edges to the scroll view’s corresponding edges. The content view now defines
>      the scroll view’s content area.
> 5. (Optional) To disable horizontal scrolling, set the content view’s width equal to the scroll view’s width. The content view now fills the
>      scroll view horizontally.
> 6. (Optional) To disable vertical scrolling, set the content view’s height equal to the scroll view’s height. The content view now fills
>      the scroll view horizontally.

Furthermore:

> Your layout must fully define the size of the content view (except
>   where defined in steps 5 and 6). … When the content view is taller than the scroll view, the scroll view enables vertical scrolling. When the content view is wider than the scroll view, the scroll view enables horizontal scrolling.

To summarize, the scroll view's content view (in this case, a stack view) must be pinned to its edges *and* have its width and/or height otherwise constrained.  That means that the contents of the stack view must be constrained (directly or indirectly) in the direction(s) in which scrolling is desired, which might mean adding a height constraint to each view inside a vertically scrolling stack view, for example.  The following is an example of how to allow for vertical scrolling of a scroll view containing a stack view:

```
// Pin the edges of the stack view to the edges of the scroll view that contains it
stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

// Set the width of the stack view to the width of the scroll view for vertical scrolling
stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks, but omitting the height constraint (to allow for vertical scrolling) yields this error in Storyboard: `Need constraints for: Y position or height.` This error only goes away if you set both a width and height constraint for the stack view, which disables vertical scrolling. Does this code still work for you?

Comment: @Crashalot To eliminate that error you need to add a subview to the stack view; see my answer below.

Answer (score 24):

#### Critical tip about `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` see below!

---

#### Up to date for 2020.

#### 100% storyboard OR 100% code.

This example is vertical:

---

#### Here's the simplest possible explanation:

1. Have a blank full-screen scene
2. Add a scroll view. Control-drag from the scroll view **to the base view**, add left-right-top-bottom, all zero.
3. Add a stack view in the scroll view.  Control-drag from the stack view **to the scroll view**, add left-right-top-bottom, all zero.
4. Put two or three labels inside the stack view.

For clarity, make the background color of the label red. Set the label height to 100.

5. Now set the **width** of each UILabel:

   Surprisingly, control-drag from the `UILabel` to the scroll view, **not** to the stack view, and select **equal widths**.

To repeat:

#### Don't control drag from the UILabel to the UILabel's parent - go to the grandparent. (In other words, go all the way to the scroll view, do not go to the stack view.)

It's that simple. That's the secret.

> *Secret tip - Apple bug:*
>
> *It **will not work** with only one item! Add a few labels to make the demo work.*

You're done.

Tip: You **must add a height to every new item**. Every item in any scrolling stack view must have either an intrinsic size (such as a label) or add an explicit height constraint.

---

The alternative approach:

To recap the above approach: surprisingly, set the widths of the labels to the width of the scroll view (not the stack view).

Here is an alternate approach...

#### Drag from the stack view to the scroll view, and add a "width equal" constraint. This seems strange because *you already pinned left-right*, but *that is how you do it*. No matter how strange it seems that's the secret.

So you have two options:

1. Surprisingly, set the width of each item in the stack view to the width of the scrollview grandparent (***not the stackview parent***).

or

2. Surprisingly, set a "width equal" of the stackview to the scrollview - ***even though*** you do have the left and right edges of the stackview pinned to the scrollview anyway.

To be clear, do ONE of those methods, do NOT do both.

---

## !! CRITICAL TIP !!

UIKit has a demented feature, `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`

It breaks all scrolling on scroll views. (The view will scroll wildly "in all directions".)

You have to do this with all scroll views:

```
class Example: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var yourScrollView: UIScrollView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        yourScrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        print("You must do that")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

As Eik says, `UIStackView` and `UIScrollView` play together nicely, see [here](https://gist.github.com/twostraws/a02d4cc09fc7bc16859c).

The key is that the `UIStackView` handles the variable height/width for different contents and the `UIScrollView` then does its job well of scrolling/bouncing that content:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: stackView.frame.width, height: stackView.frame.height)       
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to combine manual and auto layout to allow for a scrollable stack view.  You simply need to constrain the stack view's width and/or height.  See my answer for details and a link to the relevant Apple docs.

Comment: The github example worked perfectly and was very clear. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints= false, this did the trick in my case

Answer (score 17):

The constraints in the top-voted answer here worked for me, and I've pasted an image of the constraints below, as created in my storyboard.

I did hit two issues though that others should be aware of:

1. After adding constraints similar to those in in the accepted answer, I'd get the red autolayout error `Need constraints for: X position or width`. This was solved by adding a UILabel as a subview of the stack view.

   I'm adding the subviews programmatically, so I originally had no subviews on the storyboard. To get rid of the autolayout errors, add a subview to the storyboard, then remove it on load before adding your real subviews and constraints.
2. I originally attempted to add `UIButtons` to the UIStackView. The buttons and views would load, but the **scroll view would not scroll**. This was solved by adding `UILabels` to the Stack View instead of buttons. Using the same constraints, this view hierarchy with the UILabels scrolls but the UIButtons does not.

   I'm confused by this issue, as the UIButtons *do* seem to have an IntrinsicContentSize (used by the Stack View). If anyone knows why the buttons don't work, I'd love to know why.

Here is my view hierarchy and constraints, for reference:

[image: constraints for stack view in scroll view[1]]

Comment: you just saved me a bunch of hours of head bumping against the wall and frustration, I am in exactly the same situation and could not figure out the reason of the warning and why is not working with buttons. Why Apple why!?

Comment: I added a label and kept my buttons and that got scrolling to work after much frustration. If you are adding buttons programmatically this is the way to go

Answer (score 16):

### Horizontal Scrolling (UIStackView within UIScrollView)

For horizontal scrolling. First, create a `UIStackView` and a `UIScrollView` and add them to your view in the following way:

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
let stackView = UIStackView()

scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

Remembering to set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` on the `UIStackView` and the `UIScrollView`:

```
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

To get everything working the trailing, leading, top and bottom anchors of the `UIStackView` should be equal to the `UIScrollView` anchors:

```
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

But the width anchor of the `UIStackView` must the equal to or greater than the width of the `UIScrollView` anchor:

```
stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Now anchor your `UIScrollView`, for example:

```
scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Next, I would suggest trying the following settings for the `UIStackView` alignment and distribution:

```
topicStackView.axis = .horizontal
topicStackView.distribution = .equalCentering
topicStackView.alignment = .center

topicStackView.spacing = 10
```

Finally you'll need to use the `addArrangedSubview:` method to add subviews to your UIStackView.

### Text Insets

One additional feature that you might find useful is that because the `UIStackView` is held within a `UIScrollView` you now have access to text insets to make things look a bit prettier.

```
let inset:CGFloat = 20
scrollView.contentInset.left = inset
scrollView.contentInset.right = inset

// remember if you're using insets then reduce the width of your stack view to match
stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: topicScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -inset*2).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 14):

I was looking to do the same thing and stumbled upon this [excellent post.](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/scrolling-stack-views/) If you want to do this programmatically using the anchor API, this is the way to go.

To summarize, embed your `UIStackView` in your `UIScrollView`, and set the anchor constraints of the `UIStackView` to match those of the `UIScrollView`:

**Objective-C:**

```
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.leadingAnchor).active = true;
stackView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.trailingAnchor).active = true;
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.bottomAnchor).active = true;
stackView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.topAnchor).active = true;
stackView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.widthAnchor).active = true;
```

**Swift:**

```
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43408435/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Comment: They're not really duplicates in this case. The other question asks specifically how to do it *programmatically* while this one doesn't. Indeed, the top answer for this question provides a GUI method for achieving the result. Nonetheless, a programmatic solution might be valuable to some users.

Answer (score 7):

Just add this to `viewdidload`:

```
let insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
scrollVIew.contentInset = insets
scrollVIew.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
```

source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html

Comment: Can't tell you how much this saved my Autolayout + ScrollView woes. Great find on that Apple link.

Comment: what does do? What happens without this?

Comment: This only places scroll view content below the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

You can try **ScrollableStackView** : https://github.com/gurhub/ScrollableStackView

It's Objective-C and Swift compatible library. It's available through [CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html).

**Sample Code (Swift)**

```
import ScrollableStackView

var scrollable = ScrollableStackView(frame: view.frame)
view.addSubview(scrollable)

// add your views with 
let rectangle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 55))
rectangle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
scrollable.stackView.addArrangedSubview(rectangle)
// ...
```

**Sample Code (Objective-C)**

```
@import ScrollableStackView

ScrollableStackView *scrollable = [[ScrollableStackView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
scrollable.stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillProportionally;
scrollable.stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
scrollable.stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
[self.view addSubview:scrollable];

UIView *rectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 55)];
[rectangle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

// add your views with
[scrollable.stackView addArrangedSubview:rectangle]; 
// ...
```

Comment: Hi Peter, actually a great idea! Contributions are always welcome, please feel free to send a pull request for this. Best.

Answer (score 2):

Adding some new perspective for macOS Catalyst. Since macOS apps support window resizing, it is possible that your `UIStackView` will transition from an unscrollable status to a scrollable one, or vice versa. There are two subtle things here:

- `UIStackView` is designed to fit all area it can.
- During the transition, `UIScrollView` will attempt to resize its bounds to account for the newly gained/lost area underneath your navigation bar (or toolbar in the case of macOS apps).

This will unfortunately create an infinite loop. I am not extremely familiar with `UIScrollView` and its `adjustedContentInset`, but from my log in its `layoutSubviews` method, I am seeing the following behavior:

- One enlarges the window.
- `UIScrollView` attempts to shrink its bounds (since no need for the area underneath the toolbar).
- `UIStackView` follows.
- Somehow `UIScrollView` is unsatisfied, and decide to restore to the larger bounds. This feels very odd to me since what I am seeing from the log is that `UIScrollView.bounds.height == UIStackView.bounds.height`.
- `UIStackView` follows.
- Then loop to step 2.

It appears to me that two steps would fix the issue:

- Align `UIStackView.top` to `UIScrollView.topMargin`.
- Set `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` to `.never`.

Here I am concerned with a vertically scrollable view with a vertically growing `UIStackView`. For a horizontal pair, change the code accordingly.

Hope it helps anyone in the future. Couldn't find anyone mentioning this on the Internet and it costed me quite a long time to figure out what happened.

Answer (score 1):

If any one looking for horizontally scrollview

```
func createHorizontalStackViewsWithScroll() {
    self.view.addSubview(stackScrollView)
    stackScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 85).isActive = true
    stackScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: visualEffectViews.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackScrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    
    stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
    stackView.spacing = 5
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    
    for i in 0 ..< images.count {
        let photoView = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 85, height: 85))
        // set button image
        photoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        photoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: photoView.frame.height).isActive = true
        photoView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: photoView.frame.width).isActive = true
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(photoView)
    }
    stackView.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way for dynamic elements in stackview embed in scrollview. In XIB, add a UIStackView inside an UIScrollView and add constraints that the stackview fit the scrollview (top, bottom, lead, trail) and add a constraint to match horizontal center between them. But marked "remove at build time" the last constraint. It make XIB happy and avoid errors.

Example for horizontal scroll:
[image: Constraints]

Then:
[image: remove at buildtime]

Then in your code, just add elements like buttons in your stackview like this:

```
array.forEach { text in
     let button = ShadowButton(frame: .zero)
     button.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
     myStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
     button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
     button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constraint to center the Stack View vertically inside the scroll view, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

1. First and foremost design your view, preferably in something like Sketch or get an
   idea of what do you want as a scrollable content.
2. After this make the view controller free form (choose from attribute
       inspector) and set height and width as per the intrinsic content
       size of your view (to be chosen from the size inspector).
3. After this in the view controller put a scroll view and this is a
   logic,  which I have found to be working almost all the times in iOS (it may require going through the documentation of that view class which one can obtain via command + click on that class or via googling)

   **If you are working with two or more views then first start with a  view, which has been introduced earlier or is more primitive and then go to the view which has been introduced 
   later or is more modern. So here since scroll view has been
   introduced first,  start with the scroll view first and then go to the
   stack view. Here  put scroll view constraints to zero in all direction vis-a-vis its super view. Put all your views inside this scroll view and then put them in stack view.**

While working with stack view

- First start with grounds up(bottoms up approach), ie., if you have labels, text fields and images in your view, then lay out these views first (inside the scroll view) and after that put them in the stack view.
- After that tweak the property of stack view. If  desired view is still not achieved, then use another stack view.
- If still not achieved then play with compression resistance or content hugging priority.
- After this add constraints to the stack view.
- Also think of using an empty UIView as filler view, if all of the above is not giving satisfactory results.

After making your view, put a constraint between the mother stack view and the scroll view, while constraint children stack view with the mother stack view.
Hopefully by this time it should work fine or you may get a warning from Xcode giving suggestions, read what it says and implement those. Hopefully now you should have a working view as per your expectations:).

Answer (score 0):

Example for a vertical stackview/scrollview (using the `EasyPeasy` for autolayout):

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
scrollView <- [
    Edges(),
    Width().like(self.view)
]

let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: yourSubviews)
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.distribution = .fill    
stackView.spacing = 10
scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
stackView <- [
    Edges(),
    Width().like(self.view)
]
```

Just make sure that each of your subview's height is defined!

Answer (score 0):

For nested or single Stack view scroll view must be set a fixed width with the root view. Main stack view which is inside of scroll view must set the same width. [My scroll view is bellow of a View ignore it]

> Set up an equal Width constraint between the UIStackView and
>   UIScrollView.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Place a scroll view on your scene, and size it so that it fills the scene. Then, place a stack view inside the scroll view, and place the add item button inside the stack view. As soon as everything’s in place, set the following constraints:

```
Scroll View.Leading = Superview.LeadingMargin
Scroll View.Trailing = Superview.TrailingMargin
Scroll View.Top = Superview.TopMargin
Bottom Layout Guide.Top = Scroll View.Bottom + 20.0
Stack View.Leading = Scroll View.Leading
Stack View.Trailing = Scroll View.Trailing
Stack View.Top = Scroll View.Top
Stack View.Bottom = Scroll View.Bottom
Stack View.Width = Scroll View.Width
```

[image]

code:`Stack View.Width = Scroll View.Width` is the key.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the number of views inside the stackView was variable and I wanted to center the items. So, for instance, with one view in the stackView, I wanted this view to be centered in the middle of the screen, and if all the views did not fit inside the screen, I wanted the view to be scrollable.

This is the hierarchy of my view.

[image]

So I set a fixed width for the button, then, for the **stackView**:

- Same fixed width as the button but with 650 priority.
- Align X center to containerView
- Trailing >= 0 and leading >= 0 to containerView
- Bottom and top space to containerView

[image]

For the **containerView**:

- Trailing, leading, bottom, top, equal height, equal width (250 priority) to superview
- Fixed height

[image]

For the **scrollView**:

- Trailing, leading, bottom, top to superview

The scrollView is also embedded in a view that has leading and trailing constraints.

[image]

And about the code I used to approach this:

```
for index in 0...array.count - 1 {

      if index == 0 {
          firstButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
      } else {
          let button = UIButton()
          button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
          stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
          stackView.setNeedsLayout()
      }
}
containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
        
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
stackView.spacing = 10
stackView.alignment = .fill
```

Answer (score 0):

something everyone seems to have missed when doing this with Storyboard is FIX THE MULTIPLIER!
When you're following the steps above in anyones tutorial and resetting the constant to 0 also check the multiplier and reset it to 1, it will have taken on some other factor when visually linking to remain in place

I found I can make a LOOOOOOOOOOOONG text block squash or stretch in a UIStackView simply with

Simply
Add constraints to the scrollview
Top left bottom right, cons 0

Add constraints to the stack view pointing at the scrollbars Content Layout Guide

Then add equal width or equal height constraint from the Frame Layout Guide.
Pick : width if the content needs to scroll vertically,  height if it needs to scroll horizontally.

Now here is the key. Edit each constraint and reset the constant to 0 AND set the multiplier back to 1!!!!!

It gets wonky if you don't

If it works you can click on the inner content and mouse scroll