# Issue with Autolayout and StackView while using ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

I a trying to create a `UIScrollView` that fits exactly the contents of its subviews. I do this with a `StackView` and the scroll view's height is determined by how much content there is in the stack view. Within the stack views, there are views that contain an `UIImageView` and a `UITextView`
[image]

The `UIScrollView` starts below the title view, however every time I want to add another view (which it should scroll when the content is bigger than the actual frame) there is an issue with the scroll view's Y position. This works perfectly if I only add `UILabels` and `UITextFields`, using the same procedure

[image]

How can I do it so I can programmatically add views on the stack view that includes an `UIImageView` and a `UITextView`, just as the View Controller with labels and textfields does.

You can download my app project at the following url
https://github.com/francisc112/DescriptionWithImageApp.git

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668970/is-it-possible-for-uistackview-to-scroll

Comment: Why not opt for a table view?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a scroll view why don't you use a table view and create a custom cell with the stackview and its contents inside the cell and you can dequeue the same cell for adding multiple information.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to open your project

[image]

So I Tried opening your StoryBoard and Re-Viewing your constraints Applied , here is what I have Done Please check in following Link

Link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D-dzKsSqpx7dWsI5fYRdAfCMY_vENoIR/view?usp=sharing

**View Hierarchy**
[image]

**Note** - For such output I will prefer using a TableView instead of StackView as Same output can easily be achieved using TableView