# Need guide/resource/help on creating this UI on Swift with UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, mobile, uikit

[image: image 1]

Hi there, just like what the title says, I am in need of guidance/help on how to achieve similar UI design style as what's embedded above. I understand using UIKit could be harder as opposed to SwiftUI, but I am told to use UIKit as part of my study. Any help is much appreciated.

Edit:
We could start from the top, IE: maybe it's a custom collectionView? or static tableview?

Is the "variation" tab a collectionview inside a tableview cell?
How to achieve the "buy" and 'sell" section?

Answer (score 1):

I always use `UIStackView` for multiple views like this, it's easy to setup, to configure and to update.

**orange** views are vertical `UIStackView`, play with spacing, distribution and other properties of `UIStackView` to get it fit.

[image]

Also if you think height of views get bigger of user screen, simply drop root stackView to `UIScrollView`, find out more [how to have scrollable UIStackView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35136217/5102722)

Comment: Thank you so much! Will definitely give this a shot!

Answer (score 1):

Masoud provided a great answer regarding the layout of the screen.

as for the question "How to achieve the "buy" and 'sell" section?",
You might be interested in the UITextField's `.layer.cornerRadius` property.

Comment: Yep, just read through the documentation - seems like a solid start. Thanks!