# Swift, Scroll View, Stack View, programatical Button Creation and Auto Layout causes weird Behaviors / Errors

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have a simple iOS App, containing a Scroll View (scroll horizontally, but mainly as described here: [Is it possible for UIStackView to scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668970/is-it-possible-for-uistackview-to-scroll)). By default the Horizontal Stack is empty (spacing = Standard, Distribution is Fill, but also Equal Spacing does not improve this), and I add buttons programatically to it (for example purpose I add a random length string, to have various sizes), using:

```
filterStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
let newButtonConfiguration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
let newButton = UIButton(configuration: newButtonConfiguration)
newButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
newButton.setTitle("\(randomString(length: Int.random(in: 5..<25)))", for: .normal)
newButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "xmark.circle", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .unspecified)), for: .normal)
newButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newButtonPressedAction), for: .touchUpInside)
filterStackView.addArrangedSubview(newButton)
```

I already tried adding to the button:

```
newButton.sizeToFit()
newButton.layoutIfNeeded()
```

or to the View Stack:

```
filterStackView.sizeToFit()
filterStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Without any visible change. The weird things happening are:

[image]

After adding another one, sizes start changing in a funny way (if buttons are added from Story Board they really respect the width of the text - and Autolayout works fine):

[image]

And after playing with adding and removing them for a while:

[image]

And in the debug console I see constraints failing badly:

```
2022-11-01 14:05:48.450435+0100 TestAppSideScroll[20626:640959] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001b58c80 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[UIButton:0x122408660'N6xoAsl']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x1505080c0 )>",
    "<_UISystemBaselineConstraint:0x600001b586e0 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIButton:0x1223095d0'oHSryjPsjrZA']-(NSLayoutAnchorConstraintSpace(8))-[UIButton:0x122408660'N6xoAsl']   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<_UISystemBaselineConstraint:0x600001b586e0 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIButton:0x1223095d0'oHSryjPsjrZA']-(NSLayoutAnchorConstraintSpace(8))-[UIButton:0x122408660'N6xoAsl']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Which actually makes no sense, since the conflict seems to be the spacing constraint with the connection to the canvas constraint? But that I would expect to happen for every single button I add, if that would be the general problem - however there are no real constraints, except the spacing and the snapping of the scroll view.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah... something really weird going on there.

My *guess* would be that UIKit has some sort of algorithm that is trying to apply "readability" to the buttons. Clearly, though, that's not the goal here.

After some quick testing, one way to get around this is to add the button as a subview to a clear "container" view, and then add that container view to the stack view.

Some sample code:

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let filterStackViewA: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.spacing = 8
        v.distribution = .fill
        v.alignment = .center
        return v
    }()
    
    let filterStackViewB: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.spacing = 8
        v.distribution = .fill
        v.alignment = .center
        return v
    }()
    
    let scrollViewA: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        return v
    }()
    
    let scrollViewB: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .darkGray

        let addBtn = UIButton()
        addBtn.setTitle("Add Button", for: [])
        addBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        addBtn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        addBtn.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        addBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 8

        let labelA: UILabel = {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.textColor = .white
            v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .light)
            v.text = "Buttons added to \"Container\" views..."
            return v
        }()
        
        let labelB: UILabel = {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.textColor = .white
            v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .light)
            v.text = "Buttons added directly to stack view..."
            return v
        }()
        
        [addBtn, scrollViewA, scrollViewB, filterStackViewA, filterStackViewB, labelA, labelB].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        view.addSubview(addBtn)
        
        view.addSubview(labelA)
        
        view.addSubview(scrollViewA)
        scrollViewA.addSubview(filterStackViewA)

        view.addSubview(labelB)
        
        view.addSubview(scrollViewB)
        scrollViewB.addSubview(filterStackViewB)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        let cgA = scrollViewA.contentLayoutGuide
        let fgA = scrollViewA.frameLayoutGuide
        
        let cgB = scrollViewB.contentLayoutGuide
        let fgB = scrollViewB.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            addBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            addBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            addBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),

            labelA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addBtn.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            labelA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            labelA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            scrollViewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelA.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            scrollViewA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollViewA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollViewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),

            filterStackViewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cgA.topAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            filterStackViewA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cgA.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            filterStackViewA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cgA.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            filterStackViewA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cgA.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),

            filterStackViewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fgA.heightAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            labelB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filterStackViewA.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            labelB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            labelB.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            scrollViewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelB.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            scrollViewB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollViewB.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollViewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
            
            filterStackViewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cgB.topAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            filterStackViewB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cgB.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            filterStackViewB.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cgB.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            filterStackViewB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cgB.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            
            filterStackViewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fgB.heightAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
        ])
        
        addBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    }
    
    @objc func addButton() {

        // unwrap optional system image
        guard let img = UIImage(systemName: "xmark.circle", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .unspecified))
        else { return }
        
        var newButtonConfiguration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()

        newButtonConfiguration.title = randomString(length: Int.random(in: 5..<15))
        newButtonConfiguration.image = img

        // let's add a new button to a "container" view
        let newButtonA = UIButton(configuration: newButtonConfiguration)
        newButtonA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let v = UIView()
        v.addSubview(newButtonA)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            newButtonA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.topAnchor),
            newButtonA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.leadingAnchor),
            newButtonA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.trailingAnchor),
            newButtonA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        // add the container view to the stack view
        filterStackViewA.addArrangedSubview(v)
        
        // let's add a new button directly to the stack view
        let newButtonB = UIButton(configuration: newButtonConfiguration)
        filterStackViewB.addArrangedSubview(newButtonB)

        newButtonA.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeMe(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        newButtonB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeMe(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        // let's make sure the new button is visible
        //  note: this is just for example...
        //  if we rapidly tap and add buttons, this can easily "miss" the last button
        //  so don't expect this to be "production" code
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let sz = self.scrollViewA.contentSize
            let rA = CGRect(x: sz.width - 1.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
            self.scrollViewA.scrollRectToVisible(rA, animated: true)
            let szB = self.scrollViewB.contentSize
            let rB = CGRect(x: szB.width - 1.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
            self.scrollViewB.scrollRectToVisible(rB, animated: true)
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc func removeMe(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // get a reference to the tapped button's superview
        guard let sv = sender.superview else { return }
        
        var v: UIView!

        if sv is UIStackView {
            // we tapped a button added directly to the stack view
            v = sender
        } else {
            // we tapped a button that's in a "container" view
            v = sv
        }

        guard let st = v.superview as? UIStackView,
              let idx = st.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: v),
              filterStackViewA.arrangedSubviews.count > idx,
              filterStackViewB.arrangedSubviews.count > idx
        else {
            print("something's not setup right, so return")
            return
        }
        
        let bA = filterStackViewA.arrangedSubviews[idx]
        let bB = filterStackViewB.arrangedSubviews[idx]

        // let's animate the buttons away
        bA.isHidden = true
        bB.isHidden = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { _ in
            bA.removeFromSuperview()
            bB.removeFromSuperview()
        })

    }
    
    func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
    }
}
```

It will look like this when running:

[image]

Each tap of "Add Button" will add a new button to each scrolling-stackView, with the top set using buttons in container views. Tapping any of those buttons will remove it from its stack view, along with its "twin" from the other one.

Comment: Works like a charm - wrapped in the view and then it shows up correctly. The constraint crash is also gone. The only thing I will still have to investigate is, since above code uses also the broken approach, why if you create the scroll view by code the constrain things do not crash, and if you create by story board it does.