# Vertical Paging UIScrollView incorrect height

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to implement a snapping scroll view like that of an Instagram Reels UI. The contents are in SwiftUI, and the scroll view is a `UIScrollView` wrapped in `UIViewRepresentable`. I enable paging on the `UIScrollView` to get the snap to item on scroll feature.

The contents of the scroll view is just some Texts that I set to full width and height of the screen:

```swift
struct FeedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("")
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                .background(.red)
            Text("")
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                .background(.green)
            Text("")
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                .background(.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

The scroll view representable is as follows:

```swift
struct ScrollSnapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.isPagingEnabled = true
        view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        view.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        
        let child = UIHostingController(rootView: FeedView())
        child.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 3)
        view.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 3)
        view.addSubview(child.view)
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

And then I instantiate a `ScrollSnapView` with `ignoreSafeArea` in the main struct:

```swift
@main
struct App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ScrollSnapView()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a recording of the scrolling:

[image]

As you can see, when I scroll to the second page, there is a little red visible on the top. And when I scroll to the third page, there is a little green visible. How can I make `UIScrollView` page to the exact bounds of each page?

I've tried removing this line in `makeUIView`:

```swift
view.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

It includes the safe area bounds when paging (which I don't want, I want to completely hide the safe area), but at least it fully scrolls to the top bound of each page.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24692182/9147089) answer, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Seems you miss a contentInset setup to a 0. Try to add this in the ScrollSnapView initialization: view.contentInset = .zero

Comment: @MassimoPavanel Nope, doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `.ignoresSafeArea()` in the `VStack`

```
struct FeedView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Text("")
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            .background(.red)
        Text("")
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            .background(.green)
        Text("")
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            .background(.blue)
    }.ignoresSafeArea()  //notice this line
  }
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks a lot! I guess the ignoreSafeArea on the ScrollSnapView in the main App struct does not get passed to the subview.