# How can I create a popover which contains a scrollView automatically scrolled to the top?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift3, uistoryboard, uipopover

I am presenting a popover like this:

```
    let popoverContent = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: segueIdentifiers.informationPopover))! as UIViewController
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContent)
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
    let popover = nav.popoverPresentationController
    popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 500,height: 600)
    popover?.delegate = self
    popover?.sourceView = self.view
    popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

    self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

The popover being created is from a `viewController` created in the `storyboard`.

The `viewController` with the `popover` is created has the following layout.

```
--View
---Scroll View
----View
-----Text View
```

I initially had a problem where there was an awkward amount of space in between the top of the container and the `Text View`. Using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630059/why-uiscrollview-is-leaving-space-from-top-in-ios-6-and-ios-7) I saw I could remove the `Adjusts Scroll View Insets`. That fixed the awkward spacing at the top issue but when the `scrollView` presents itself, it is still scrolled a third of the way down and some of the text at the top is hidden.

**Issue:** 
The `scrollView` is a third of the way scrolled down when it is presented.

**Questions:** 
Is there a way to initialize the `scrollView` to be automatically scrolled at the top using the `storyboard`, i.e., a run-time attribute? If not, how can I do this programmatically since I am creating the `popover` programmatically via a storyboard ID?

**Update 1**
I tried subclassing my `viewController` and creating an outlet for the `scrollView`. In my `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, `viewDidAppear`, and `viewWillLayoutSubviews` I tried the below code. This did not solve my issue.

```
let scroll2TopOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
self.aboutUsScrollView.setContentOffset(scroll2TopOffset, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: The `textView` needs to have its scrolling turned off in the `viewDidLoad` and then turned back on in the `viewDidAppear`

```
class AboutUsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var aboutUsTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        aboutUsTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        aboutUsTextView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Will leave question open - would like to know if there is a better way of doing this.