# Can't get rid of a UIviewcontroller header

Tags: swift

I am trying to get rid of a header(extra-padding) that appears on the top of my view when I run the simulator. I have tried by setting the layout reference size to zero but is not working. The collectionview is only a small part of my screen that is why I'm not sure what it is. The header looks like that of a navigationview.

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize.zero
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    return cv
}()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20630386/4042468

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the help! I finally realized what it was, I'm doing my views programmatically and didn't realize that my view was a navigationController.

Here's what did it for me:
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true;

Answer (score 0):

1. With translucent navigation view controller's view content starts from top of navigation bar. If you want to layout view to start from bottom of navigation bar, set `isTranslucent` to false (available in interface builder).
2. Use proper `contentInset` of collection view